# RelayContainer: `Relay` was rendered with invalid Relay context `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

i'm using ReactJS, Relay Framework and GrapthQL. This is the layout component where i use relay to get data:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

import Header from '../Header';
import Footer from '../Footer';
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar';
import Relay from 'react-relay';

import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

class Layout extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const {children} = this.props;
        var communityList = this.props.communityList;
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    <Sidebar/>
                    {React.Children.only(children)}
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}

Layout.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
};

var RelayLayout =  Relay.createContainer(Layout, {
    fragments: {
        communityList: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Layout {
    user(id: 11) {
        connections{
          community{
            name
            }
        }
    }
  }
    `,
    },
});


export default RelayLayout;
```

The problem is: when i run the page, it show the error message:

> *Invariant Violation RelayContainer: `Relay(Layout)` was rendered with invalid Relay context `undefined`. Make sure the `relay` property on
>   the React context conforms to the `RelayEnvironment` interface.*

The query using GrapthQL return valid data so i don't think problem is the query

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I was running my tests. You need to wrap the Relay container with a Relay.RootContainer or Relay.Renderer component. Like this:

```
const ViewerQuery = { viewer: () => Relay.QL`query { viewer }` };

const queryConfig = {
  queries: ViewerQuery,
  params: {},
  name: 'User'
};

<Relay.Renderer
    Container={User}
    queryConfig={ViewerQuery}
    environment={Relay.Store}
    render={({done, error, props, retry, stale}) => {}} />
```